# gtkmm3.0 правильная обработка callback функции при клике на кнопку

Tags: c++, gtk

Идея проста, пишу расширение для php которое выводит с помощью gtkmm окно с двумя кнопками. "upload" и "cancel". Сразу оговорюсь с c++ всего несколько дней как познакомился и тут код прототип (он работает)

```
/**
 * run preview window
 * @param param
 * @return string "upload" | "cancel"
 */
Php::Value GtkPhp::preview(Php::Parameters &param) {
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv = NULL;
    char *file = nullptr;

    std::string fileSrc = param[0];
    file = new char[fileSrc.size() + 1];
    std::copy(fileSrc.begin(), fileSrc.end(), file);
    file[fileSrc.size()] = '\0';

    Php::Value srcPic = param[0];

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.gtkphp7");
    auto refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();

    try {
        refBuilder->add_from_file("picview.glade");
    } catch(const Glib::FileError& ex) {
        std::cerr << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex) {
        std::cerr << "BuilderError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    refBuilder->get_widget("window1",mainWindow);

    // preview picture
    Gtk::Image *image = nullptr;
    refBuilder->get_widget("preview",image);
    // button ok click
    Gtk::Button *buttonUpload = nullptr;
    refBuilder->get_widget("upload",buttonUpload);
    buttonUpload->signal_clicked().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&GtkPhp::uploadClick) );
    // button cancel click
    Gtk::Button *buttonCancel = nullptr;
    refBuilder->get_widget("cancel",buttonCancel);
    buttonCancel->signal_clicked().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&GtkPhp::cancelClick));
    image->set(file);
    app->run(*mainWindow);

    if(statusUpload == 1) {
        return "upload";
    } else {
        return "cancel";
    }
}
```

При нажатие на кнопку обрабатываются callback функции

```
/**
 * callback upload button
 */
void GtkPhp::uploadClick() {
    statusUpload = 1;
    delete mainWindow;
}

/**
 * callback cancel button
 */
void GtkPhp::cancelClick() {
    statusCancel = 1;
    delete mainWindow;
}
```

где переменные глобальные

```
int statusUpload = 0;
int statusCancel = 0;
Gtk::Window *mainWindow = nullptr;
```

тестовый php файл выглядит так

```
<?php
$gtk = new GtkPhp();
$chose = $gtk->preview("/tmp/1475441471960_screen.png");
var_dump($chose);
```

Этот код формирует превью картинки и выводит на экран с двумя кнопками upload и cancel по нажатию на кнопку в переменную chose пишеться либо 'upload' либо 'chose'.
Собственно вопрос как избежать глобальных переменных?